# React-router-redux and redux-saga CORS request issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, react-router-redux

I'm trying to implement authentication in a new React app based on Core UI, whereas I have an old functional version using another theme in Angular 5.

I tried to follow [this](https://medium.com/@stepankuzmin/authentication-with-react-router-redux-5-x-and-redux-saga-55da66b54be7) tutorial, but it gaves me this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://myapp.url (Reason: CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

every time I'm trying to login (whereas the same backend was working with Angular).

My Backend configuration is the following:

```
Origins:         "*",
Methods:         "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE",
RequestHeaders:  "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept, Token",
ExposedHeaders:  "",
```

and my Saga.js source is:import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

```
import { AUTH_REQUEST, AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_FAILURE } from './reducer';

const fetchJSON = (url, options = {}) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => (response.status !== 200 ? reject(response) : response))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => resolve(response))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });

function* authorize({ payload: { login, password } }) {
  const options = {
    body: JSON.stringify({ login, password }),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, Content-Type,  X-Requested-With, Accept'}
  };

  try {
    //TODO: replace URL by a dynamic one
    console.log(options.headers);
    const { token } = yield call(fetchJSON, 'https://myapp.url', options);
    yield put({ type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: token });
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  } catch (error) {
    let message;
    switch (error.status) {
      case 500: message = 'Internal Server Error'; break;
      case 401: message = 'Invalid credentials'; break;
      default: message = 'Something went wrong';
    }
    yield put({ type: AUTH_FAILURE, payload: message });
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
}

function* Saga() {
  yield takeLatest(AUTH_REQUEST, authorize);
}

export default Saga;
```

When I look at my backend logs, I just receive an OPTION Rest request, without any POST.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request is called `preflight request`- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.0#preflight-requests - You can setup your backend to handle that `OPTIONS` request and then send out a response with status code `200`.

Comment: You have to configure the backend for preflight. Add an `options` endpoint and append the proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: So I have to setup my server to handle:
`OPTIONS` https://myapp.url/v1/auth
and response with a status code 200 and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at `https://myapp.url/v1` ?